# Append and Pre-append \n to NSMutableString

Tags: ios

I am using the following to append a line break to my NSStrings

```
// Add line break to strings
           [attrString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n"]];
```

What I am ideally looking for is a solution to add a ***line break*** before and after the string instead of just using `\n\n` twice at the end? Is this possible?

**The full code if required can be seen here:**

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];

       for (NSString *testWord in ptpArray) {
           if ([testWord rangeOfString:@"*"].location != NSNotFound) {

               //Remove Marker
               NSString *stripped = [testWord stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"*" withString:@""];

               //Get string and add bold
               NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stripped];

               NSRange selectedRange = [stripped rangeOfString:(stripped)];

               [string beginEditing];

               [string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                              value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0]
                              range:selectedRange];

               [string endEditing];

               [attrString appendAttributedString:string];
           }
           else
           {
               [attrString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\u2022 "]];
               [attrString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:testWord]];
           }

           // Add line break to strings
           [attrString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n"]];
```

Comment: `NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@",stripped]];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSMutableAttributedString` also responds to

`- (void)insertAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)attributedString atIndex:(NSUInteger)index`.

So you could use that to insert `\n` at `index 0` (and keep on appending `\n` at the end).